# Extracting X,Y coordinates from PDF: need to return value rather than print to console

Tags: java, pdf, methods, pdfbox

I've made some very minor adjustments to org.apache.pdfbox.examples.util.printtextlocations, but I can't figure out how to return a String, List, or TextPosition object.

The parsing of the PDF is set in motion by this for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<allPages.size(); i++ ) {
    PDPage page = (PDPage)allPages.get( i );
    System.out.println( "Processing page: " + i );
    PDStream contents = page.getContents();
    if( contents != null )
        {
            printer.processStream(page, page.findResources(), 
                                  page.getContents().getStream() );
        }
}
```

And here's the relevant method:

```
public void processTextPosition( TextPosition text ) {
    System.out.println( "String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + "," +
            text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale=" +
            text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space=" +
            text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width=" +
            text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getCharacter() ); */
}
```

It prints the information I want to the console, but I'd like to be able to return the TextPosition object instead.

I've scanned through the Javadocs and source for the org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper class, but my familiarity with Java is not sufficient to figure out a solution. And, not surprisingly, if I try to change processTextPosition in my class to return a value then it produces this error ("processTextPosition(TextPosition) in PDF cannot override processTextPosition(TextPosition) in PDFTextStripper".)

Comment: As of now, I still haven't figured out a proper solution, but I did find a workaround: write all data to file then read from file to set as list.

Comment: How about adding a member variable of your choice to the `PdfTextStripper`, adding to that member in your `processTextPosition` override,  and reading the aggregated value in that member after processing?